# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params') in BookingCar.js page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting error like TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params') in BookingCar.js Page and my error image and code is

[image]

App.js code is

```
import "./App.css"; 
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Register from "./pages/Register";
import BookingCar from "./pages/BookingCar";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { ProtectedWrapper } from "./components/ProtectedRoutes";
 
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            exact
            element={
              <ProtectedWrapper>
                <Home />
              </ProtectedWrapper>
            }
          ></Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route
            path="/booking/:carid"
            element={
              <ProtectedWrapper>
                <BookingCar />
              </ProtectedWrapper>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ProtectedRoute.js code is

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
 
export function ProtectedWrapper({ children }) {
  if (localStorage.getItem("user")) {
    return children;
  } else {
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
  }
}
```

Home.js code is

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import DefaultLayout from "../components/DefaultLayout";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getAllCars } from "../redux/actions/carsActions";
import { Row, Col } from "antd";
import Spinner from "../components/Spinner";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Home() {
  const { cars } = useSelector((state) => state.carsReducer);
  const { loading } = useSelector((state) => state.alertsReducer);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllCars());
  }, []);
  return (
    <DefaultLayout>
      {loading == true && <Spinner />}
      <Row justify="center" gutter={16} className="mt-5">
        {cars.map((car) => {
          return (
            <Col lg={5} sm={24} xs={24}>
              <div className="car p-2 bs1">
                <img src={car.image} className="carimg" />
                <div className="car-content d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <div>
                    <p>{car.name}</p>
                    <p>{car.rentPerHour} Rent Per Hour /-</p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <button className="btn1 mr-2">
                      <Link to={`/booking/${car._id}`}>Book Now</Link>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Col>
          );
        })}
      </Row>
    </DefaultLayout>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

BookingCar.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import DefaultLayout from "../components/DefaultLayout";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getAllCars } from "../redux/actions/carsActions";

function BookingCar({ match }) {
  const { cars } = useSelector((state) => state.carsReducer);
  const { loading } = useSelector((state) => state.alertsReducer);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllCars());
  }, []);
  return (
    <DefaultLayout>
      <h1>Booking Page</h1>
      <h1>Car Id = {match.params.carid}</h1>
    </DefaultLayout>
  );
}

export default BookingCar;
```

In BookingCar.js i am trying to get the car details like id but i am getting error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

So please help me how to solve this issue.

Comment: component 'BookingCar' takes props as arguments, you should provide them while you are rendering this component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v6 there are no longer any route props, so no `history`, `location`, or `match` props are passed from route to component. In fact, if you look at the JSX it should be quite clear that no props are being passed to `BookingCar`.

```
<Route
  path="/booking/:carid"
  element={
    <ProtectedWrapper>
      <BookingCar />
    </ProtectedWrapper>
  }
/>
```

In RRDv6 you must use the React hooks.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function BookingCar() {
  const { carid } = useParams();

  const { cars } = useSelector((state) => state.carsReducer);
  const { loading } = useSelector((state) => state.alertsReducer);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllCars());
  }, []);
  return (
    <DefaultLayout>
      <h1>Booking Page</h1>
      <h1>Car Id = {carid}</h1>
    </DefaultLayout>
  );
}
```